# Which method is more secure between MySQLi and PDO

Tags: php, mysql, security, pdo, sql-injection

So far, I'm seeing that both MySQLi and PDO are good methods when connecting to the database. What I need is which method is more secure between the two. Especially for a person developing a site for a big project that will interact will a large number of people

Comment: Define **more** secure? What criteria for objectivity in security are you using?

Comment: Both are actively developed and implement bound variables. Security is not a strong differentiating factor between them.

Comment: They're both as secure as each other to be honest, just depends which one you're more comfortable with... refer to this link; http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/pdo-vs-mysqli-which-should-you-use/

Comment: does one scrub the data better than others? not that i have looked for it but it would be nice to see a reference to a doc or two out there that shows a before and after of user data going in and coming out cleansed prior to it hitting the engine. ya know, the normal "smith; drop table users..." nonsense

Comment: Something is either secure or it isn't, especially when it comes to simple SQL query escaping. There aren't degrees of "security". [The Great Escapism (Or: What You Need To Know To Work With Text Within Text)](http://kunststube.net/escapism/)

Comment: @DrewPierce — Difficult to do that when using server-side prepared statements :)

Comment: @DrewPierce Neither scrubs your data, if you add your parameters as strings to your SQL command string instead of binding them using a prepared statement, you're equally out of luck with both.

Comment: hard to do what, show the before and after of a parameter after a call to a particular pdo function conceptually in print? not an echo statement from the server-side

Comment: Sorry. By "more secure", I meant 'that can resist attacker to hack the database'

Comment: As in my answer I've mentioned both of them gives you escaping and prepared statements which are useful in security matter(PDO also gives named params) but it is up to you if you use them, you can still use pdo and mysqli without prepared statements which is better for queries that don't need params to be binded.

Comment: Security is made by YOU, not the language/driver you are using. They sure will provide everything that is their responsibility in security, but they can't do it alone.

Comment: Neither of them are secure. You need to take care of many cases yourself or use [SafeMysql which is indeed safe](https://github.com/colshrapnel/safemysql)

Answer (score 18):

Both libraries provide SQL injection security, as long as the developer uses them the way they were intended (proper escaping / parameter binding with prepared statements when it's needed).

There is no difference in security. The main difference between PDO and Mysqli is that PDO supports various databases and mysqli supports only MySQL. MySQLi is also a bit faster. PDO supports 12 different drivers, opposed to MySQLi, which supports MySQL only.

So about security there's no difference because they both use **prepared statements** with escaping.

Comment: +1 The operative sentence being "as long as the developer uses them the way they were intended". Many developers seem to think adding an `i` to `mysql_query` automatically removes all injection possibilities.

Comment: Alright thanks Robert.

Comment: Yes it's true :) there is always "human" factor in security. Even best security can by broken by human's fault.

Comment: Cool, any books you guys know that cover this section well? I'm still new in php...

Comment: I've read books but they were not meant only for php. It's about general security, how to handle input, escaping, santanizing, validation etc. There are a lot of articles in www where you can find best practices. It's not always about security of application but also security of server's configuration. In my apps I always check every kind of input, even if it is input where users shouldn't have access.

Comment: Alright. That makes sense Robert

Comment: +1 for the first sentence. Good answer!