# MYSQLI/PDO: How to convert MySQLi to PDO in login form

Tags: php, mysqli, pdo

I currently developed the login form with MySQLi. Since PDO is more secure than I would like to convert to PDO. Below is PHP MySQLi code at login form. For config.php, I already change to PDO.

```
                <?php
            include("config/config.php");
            session_start();

            if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {

            $Email = mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$_POST['Email']);
            $Pwd = mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$_POST['Pwd']); 

            $Pwd = md5($Pwd); 
            $sql = "SELECT staff.Email,staff.Role_ID FROM staff WHERE Email = '$Email' AND Pwd ='$Pwd'"; 
            $result = mysqli_query($link,$sql);
            $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
            $count = mysqli_num_rows($result);

            if($count == 1) {

                $_SESSION['login_user'] = $Email;

                if($row["Role_ID"] == "2"){ 
                    header("location: pages/dashboard/dashboard_admin.php");
                }else if ($row["Role_ID"] == "1"){ 
                    header("location: pages/dashboard/dashboard_super_admin.php");
                }
            }else {
                $error = "Your Login Name or Password is invalid";
                }
            }

            ?>
```

Can anyone know how to solve? Much thanks

Comment: here is good beginner guide [PDO for beginner](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp)
go for deep [PHP manual] (https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php)

Comment: As long as you implement mysqli correctly, there is no different in term of security between mysqli and PDO https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16647851/which-method-is-more-secure-between-mysqli-and-pdo

Comment: @catcon I also want to use PDO since I already change my server from mysql to mssql. mssql use pdo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no point in converting anything. Just write the PDO version right away.

A login form handler is just a regular query, nothing special. If you know how to run a query using PDO, then you know how to login.

What is much more important, is that you have to follow best practices in the security, namely [reliable password hashing](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.password-hash.php) and using prepared statements.

For a beginner it is not too easy to put everything together the right way (espeslcially given there are a lot of sites specialized in bad examples such as w3schools), so I wrote a simplified canonical example for the task, [login code using PDO](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo_examples/password_hash)

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM staff WHERE Email = ?");
$stmt->execute([$_POST['Email']]);
$row = $stmt->fetch();

if ($row && password_verify($_POST['Pwd'], $row['Pwd']))
{
    $_SESSION['login_user'] = $Email;
    if($row["Role_ID"] == "2"){ 
         header("location: pages/dashboard/dashboard_admin.php");
    }else if ($row["Role_ID"] == "1"){ 
         header("location: pages/dashboard/dashboard_super_admin.php");
    }
} else {
    $error = "Your Login Name or Password is invalid";
}
```

Note #1. PDO is not "more secure" than mysqli. It is not a driver that matters but whether you are using prepared statements or not. Both drivers have support for them but PDO prepared statements are much easier to use.

Note #2. Given there are a lot of bad examples for PDO connection as well, here is my [canonical example for the task](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo_examples/connect_to_mysql). Although it's for MySQL but you have to follow the routine, only changing the DSN part for MS SQL.

Comment: thanks, but $stmt->execute([$_POST['Email']]); got error. undefined index 'Email'

Comment: @F.Lampard you would still need to POST an `Email` field from a form. Your original code has `if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {` so you may want to keep using that if this script may be accessed by GET requests